# Loading data from another url

Tags: jquery

I am new to javascript and jquery, i load the data from another site through php but i want to refresh it every minute without use of php because they data returned is in this format **1000, 10000** offcourse the numbers are different everytime.

So how can i load the data every minute and split it, like in php i use **explode(",", "1000, 10000")**.

I want to split the data to display the % so in this example 1000/10000 * 100  will give us 10%.

Thank You.

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear on what you can't figure out?   It seems like you are asking how to split, and after your comments you are asking how to run it on an interval.   Have you got the part about loading the data from another url, or is that part needed as well?   Additionally, do you even have another url that you can hit that will return the data that you need in a usable form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the string [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function.  You can use it to take a string and split based on a regular expression.  You can then take the returned substrings and convert them to numbers in order to do the math on them.  Note that you may be able to omit the explicit conversion, but sometimes numbers are treated differently than strings (for example the `+` operator will append strings even if they are all digits) so I feel that it's a good practice.

```
 var nums = data.split( /,/ );

 var pct = Number(nums[0]) / Number(nums[1]) * 100;
```

To get the data every minute you'll need to use [AJAX](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) and call the php method that generates the numbers.  Note that either the url needs to be in the same domain or you need to use JSONP to do the transfer.  I'll assume (since you are working with a string) that the value is not JSON, but raw content.  If you can use JSON, you wouldn't need to do string splitting since you can put the numbers in individual properties of the JSON object.

```
 $(function() {
    setInterval( function() {
       $.ajax({
          url: 'some.php',
          dataType: 'html',
          success: function(data) {
               var nums = data.split( /,/ );
               $('#percentage').text( (Number(nums[0]) / Number(nums[1]) * 100) + '%' );
          }
       });
    },60000);
 });
```

Comment: But can you please tell me how to run the function every minute

Comment: +1 for passing function into setInterval...  don't understand why people insist on using strings like "someMethod()" when functions or function names work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you've already figured out how to load the data to your page, and now you just want to parse it and make use of it.

In that case, you really don't need any jquery, you can just use the javascript `split` method.

```
var dataFromOtherUrl = "1000, 10000";
var result = dataFromOtherUrl.split(", ") // result is the array: ["1000", "10000"]
```

From there you can use the values in the array to do your % math:

```
var percentage = result[0]/result[1] * 100;
```

If you want to limit the # of times the string is split you can pass another argument to the method.

Answer (score 0):

To run a function every minute you have to use the [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met_win_setinterval.asp)-Methode.

```
var activ = window.setInterval("update()", 1000*60);
function update() {
  // your update code goes here
  // Ajax-Request
  // parsing
  // updating the display
}
```

to stop it, use:

```
window.clearInterval(activ);
```